# How to memoize component when storing change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a modal in my app component, but every time when the redux store changes, the modal update itself.

The modal needs much expensive calculation, there's no need to update the modal when it's invisible.

I've to try React.memo but is not working when the Modal component has something like `useSelector`

```
<App>
  <Modal visible={visible} onClose={onClose} />//it cause perform issue
</App>
```

In my real app, the modal component

```
const arr = useSelector(reselectFn);//it's also expensive calc
const result1 = expensiveCalc(arr);//hard to memorize it's value because reselectFn returns a new array
const result2 = anotherExpensiveCalc(result1);
const result3 = yetAnotherExpensiveCalc(result2);
```

All I want is not updating the modal component when it's invisible.

some simplified code

app.jsx

```
function counter(state = 0, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "random":
      return Math.random();
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

const store = createStore(counter);

function App() {
  const num = useSelector(s => s);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const callback = useCallback(() => {
    dispatch({ type: "random" });
  }, [dispatch]);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={callback}>dispatch</button>
      <h2>{num}</h2>
      <Memo />
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

memo.jsx

```
let count = 0;

const Memo = () => {
  const s = useSelector(s => s); // it blocks memorize
  return <h2>I am render {count++} times</h2>;
};

export default React.memo(Memo, () => true);//not working when using useSelector
```

I've made a simple example [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/billowing-firefly-gge72)

Comment: How about unmount modal everytime it's invisible?

Comment: Just for reference, the term is `memoize`, not `memorize`.

Comment: `React.memo` is the functional equivalent of `PureComponent`.

Answer (score 0):

In your App.js component, set a property which is boolean as below in the initial state.

```
this.state = {
                show: false
             }
```

And then you can can write a function which changes the value of "show", when the function is being called.

```
function showModal(){
   this.setState({
     ...state,
     show : !this.state.show
})
}
```

After that you can set Modal as below

```
<Modal show={this.state.show} onHide={this.showModal} />
```